# PHP bindParam() function with multiple parameters

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following code:

```
$selectUserQuery = 'SELECT email_address, password FROM user WHERE email_address = :email_address AND password = :password';
$prepSelectUser = $conn->prepare($selectUserQuery);
/*
* HOW DO I ADD MULTIPLE PARAMETERS TO THIS BINDPARAM() FUNCTION?
*/
$prepSelectUser->bindParam(':email_address', $email, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prepSelectUser->execute();
$userResult = $prepSelectUser->fetchAll();
$userCount = count($userResult);
```

How can I add multiple parameters to the bindParam() function?

Comment: Oops, yeah, mistake. It doesn't cause any trouble though?

Comment: You just call `bindParam()` once for each parameter you wish to bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change

```
$prepSelectUser->bindParam(':email_address', $email, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

to

```
$prepSelectUser->bindParam(':email_address', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

then call another bindParam, like

```
$prepSelectUser->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Okay, yeah I noticed the mistake. I made it because I had copied this code from another website and didn't really understand PDO (it looks like Arabic at the beginning :D). I fixed it, changed it into STR. So basically, I just need to add a second bindParam() function to get this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You don't actually need this function at all. as well as most of other code you used.

```
$sql  = 'SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE email_address = ? AND password = ?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$email, $password]);
$userCount = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```